# how to configure AWS IPv6 correctly? i can telnet my IPv6 from server itself, but not from outside

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ipv6

so i hosted my application on AWS ec-2, 
i can access my ec-2 instance throught ssh "with IPv4",
i followed this guide

[AWS IPv6 migration](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html)

i have configured my IPv6, so my ec-2 instance have an IPv6,
but the problem is, when i try to connect to my ec-2 server with IPv6 like this

```
 ssh -i mos-bs-production.pem -A xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx 22
```

it gave me this error

> ssh: connect to host xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx port 22: Network is unreachable

also when i tried to telnet to my IPv6 22 from server itself it's working,
but if i tried to telnet my IPv6 22 from outside / other server it's not working.

oh FYI my server using Ubuntu 14.04, and if i tried to ping IPv6 google also not working, i guess it has connection problem?

i don't know how to explain it better,
but so far i tweak my setup in AWS VPC console like this

VPC
[image: this is my VPC]

Subnet
[image: this is my subnet]

Routes
[image: routes]

Security Group related to VPC
[image]

please advice, what i do wrong here? this is confusing.

thanks.....

Comment: Show what you have configured.

Comment: @sven i have updated my question with screen shoot, VPS setup, i don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @svlada yes i have.